# SSLError: max retries exceeded with url error? How to fix this?

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, certifi

I am attempting to scrape text off of websites, and I am using the requests module to do so.

With the given code (Facebook as an example here)

```
requests.get('http://facebook.com')
```

I receive back the following error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
pip install certifi
pip install certifi_win32
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You can try this way

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from urllib3 import disable_warnings

disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

page = requests.get('http://facebook.com', verify=False)

print(page.content)
```

Comment: Dangerous recommendation! For the same reasons mentioned in the comments of @Mostafa Alayesh's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably stems from an overly aggressive security measure that you might be able to fix in two steps:

1. Download the raw CA Bundle from https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
2. In requests.get use verify=[path to raw CA Bundle]

Comment: This is indeed the correct way to resolve this error. This should have been an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while I scraping a website. I tried setting up False to verify and I used CA certificate, both didn't work. Reading through the docs I find [Session Objects](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects)

I was making several requests to the same host for that reason I was getting "Max retries exceeded with url"

In your case, you can try this:

```
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('http://facebook.com')
```

Comment: This is the real answer right here.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but with a tiny difference.

I was trying to reach the website by IP

```
requests.get('http://10.20.30.40', verify=False)
```

And all the solutions provided was failing, until I used the domain name instead of the IP.

Comment: This solution is dangerous, as it introduces the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack, rendering any data transmitted during this communication susceptible to interception (eavesdrop) and/or manipulation (tampering).

Comment: My solution is not to `verfiy=False`, it is to use the domain name instead of IP

Comment: That's the case but in the code you provide there is also verify=False. If you do not recommend using it it is best you remove it from your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code and replace url variable with your website link

import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

s = requests.Session()

response = s.get(url, verify=False)

response.text

Comment: How is this meaningfully different from the top-voted answer?